# Migrating data between tables, what's wrong with the syntax in these cast() functions? MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO `simulations` SELECT `simulations_t`.`ExperimentID`,
    `simulations_t`.`CycleCount`,
    cast(`simulations_t`.`TimeElapsed` as `double`) as `TimeElapsed`,
    `simulations_t`.`Xa`,
    cast(`simulations_t`.`nextCycleShort` as `bit`) as `nextCycleShort`,
    cast(`simulations_t`.`PrimaryRule` as `tinyint`) as `PrimaryRule`,
    cast(`simulations_t`.`InsulinSecondaryRule` as `tinyint`) as `InsulinSecondaryRule`,
    cast(`simulations_t`.`DextroseSecondaryRule` as `tinyint`) as `DextroseSecondaryRule`,
    cast(`simulations_t`.`InsulinBolusRule` as `tinyint`) as `InsulinBolusRule`,
    cast(`simulations_t`.`DextroseBolusRule` as `tinyint`) as `DextroseBolusRule`,
    cast(`simulations_t`.`TertiaryCon` as bit) as `TertiaryCon`,
    `simulations_t`.`DEXpump_cap`,
    `simulations_t`.`INSpump_cap`,
    `simulations_t`.`VHM_G`,
    `simulations_t`.`VHM_X`,
    `simulations_t`.`VHM_I1`,
    `simulations_t`.`VHM_I2`
FROM `imtsimulations`.`simulations_t`;
```

I either see "unexpected double" when using backticks, or "unexpected simulations_t (double quoted text)" when using double quotes. I think this stems from those cast() functions, but I want to do this table in a different way than the other one. I'm not sure how else to do this, as each error has a solution that makes the other error; when using backticks, I saw I needed to change to double quotes, and when using double quotes, I saw that I needed to change to backticks.

Comment: I'm an Oracle guy, not MySQL, but the obvious question is... did you try no ticks or quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Check out mysql [cast()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast).

There are specific types that can be cast to, and they differ from acutal column definition types. Also, backticks are unnecessary surrounding the type. Backticks are for object definition names (tables, columns, etc...) that either conflict with reserved words or have space in them or otherwise would cause illegal syntax.

```
select cast("01" as decimal(2,1)), cast("1" as unsigned integer);
# 1.0    1
```

Comment: There's two that I'm casting as bit, they're currently text (1 or 0). The others are currently int, I want to cast them as tinyint. They are all no larger than 217, so tinyint is perfect.

Comment: For the bit you could use, `IF(column = 1,b'1',b'0')`. The other casts may not be necessary. What are the type mappings?

Comment: TINYINT can hold values between -127 and 127. If you are storing 217, then you'll need at least `SMALLINT`.